# Java httpsUrlConnection:: Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, client-certificates

I am facing issues with client certificate authetication with java httpsurlconnection,
I tried through curl it works(curl --request https://someurl --cert client_cert.pem --key client_key.pem --insecure), but it does not work with java, 
I have 2 certificates - client and key. Created keystore for client and key pem files.

example:: openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey client_key.pem -in client_cert.pem -out client.p12 -passout pass:Password123 -name test

I am getting "no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication", see below

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 04                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
check handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
update handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
Certificate chain




package com.example.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HttpsUrlTest
{
  final String KEYSTOREPATH = "c:\\test\\identity.p12";
  final char[] KEYSTOREPASS = "Password123".toCharArray();
  final char[] KEYPASS = "Password123".toCharArray();

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
    {
      HttpsUrlTest t1 = new HttpsUrlTest();
      String httpsURL = "https://someurl/api/v1/details";
      URL myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
      HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
      conn.setSSLSocketFactory(t1.getSSLFactories().getSocketFactory());
      //conn.setHostnameVerifier(new TrustAnyHostnameVerifier());
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setUseCaches(false);
      conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
      conn.setConnectTimeout(8 * 1000);
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      String text;
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      while ((text = in.readLine()) != null)
        result.append(text);
      in.close();
      System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public SSLContext getSSLFactories()
  {
    try
    {
      InputStream storeStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTOREPATH);
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      keyStore.load(storeStream, "Password123".toCharArray());
      KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      keyFactory.init(keyStore, "Password123".toCharArray());
      KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      TrustManager[] tm = {new TrustAnyTrustManager() };
      //SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");  // ("TLS", "SunJSSE");
      //sslContext.init(null, tm, new java.security.SecureRandom());

      sslContext.init(keyManagers, tm, new java.security.SecureRandom());
      SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
      return sslContext;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
  private static class TrustAnyHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier
  {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  private class TrustAnyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager
  {
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      return null;
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException
    {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is urgent can anyone help here please, Also I tried with both SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); and SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

Comment: In wireshark, I am seeing certificate, certificate key exchange messages but certficate verify message is missing. Even in node js also it works when i pass both l pass client and key pem files. const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false, // (NOTE: this will disable client verification)
        cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/client_cert.pem'),
        key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/client_key.key'),
        passphrase: ""
      
      })  I am getting unauthorized message 401 in java. Not sure whether any alias or issuer mismatch, how can i bypass this

Comment: anyone can help in this??